# Пути к файлам и папкам в GULP

Tags: gulp

У меня есть функция с путями к SVG-спрайтам. Сами спрайты, хранятся в папке `images/icons`. Как сделать так, чтобы в папке `icons` я мог создавать под папки, откуда бы я мог также брать картинки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так можно будет брать файлы с любым расширением в независимости от вложенности:

```
return gulp.src('app/images/icons/**/*')
```

Если необходимо брать все файлы с определённым расширением, но также в независимости от вложенности, тогда поможет такая конструкция:

```
return gulp.src('app/images/icons/**/*.svg')
```

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
gulp.task('iconfont', () => {
    return gulp.src('app/images/icons/**/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSprite())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(CONFIG.path + 'images'))
})
```